# Error message when sending an array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I am writing a function with the purpose of swapping the first and last elements in an array, and a main function to test it. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//function a
firsttolast (int x[], int size)
{
    int temp1;
    int temp2;
    temp1 = x[0];
    temp2 = x[(size - 1)];
    x[0] = temp2;
    x[(size - 1)] = temp1;
}

int main()
{
    int X = 10;
    int array[10];
    cout << "Please enter " << X << " integer elements of an array." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    firsttolast (array[10], X);
    for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)
        cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

The error is in this line:

```
firsttolast (array[10],X);
```

And is as follows:

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

[Error] initializing argument 1 of 'double firsttolast(int*, int)' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: you should pass in `array`, because when you do `array[10]`, you are trying to pass in `int&` into the function

Comment: `firsttolast (array[10],X);` isn't valid c++ syntax! `firsttolast (array,X);` is.

Comment: If you want to do things the "C++ way" then consider instead `std::swap(x[0], x[size - 1]);`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: it is valid **syntax**, it's invalid **semantic** because the function expects a pointer to int and `array[10]` is instead an int reference. The compiler is complaining because the type is wrong, not because the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @6502 Well, is not compiling code considered _valid syntax_ recently? I'd say no. The semantical errors are well caught up at compile time for this case and result in a **syntactical error**.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If it compiles the syntax is valid, yes. If it doesn't compile then the syntax *might still* be valid. Syntax deals with language *grammar* -- not with *meaning*. It's like how the English sentence "this statement is false" is grammatically correct (no syntax problems) but is nonsense because it has no valid meaning.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To put it another way, the definition of syntax is "the arrangement of words and phrases to create well-formed sentences in a language." The erroneous line in this source code is *well formed according to the C++ grammar* -- given the productions in the grammar it will parse successfully. However, when the compiler goes to *interpret* the "C++ sentence" it will find that its *meaning* doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

When calling the function you need just to omit the `[10]` part: the code becomes...

```
firsttolast(array, X);
```

The reason for the error is that `array[10]` is a single element (and by the way one that doesn't exist because it would be the eleventh in an array of ten elements).